# How to get javafx webview url

Tags: java, url, javafx, webview

I am trying to make a web browser with javafx, but I need to get the url of the website that the user is on. I tryed using `getDocument()`, but that didn't work, and there's no `getUrl()` method. Will you tell me how I can accomplish this.

Comment: A `WebView` does not, but [`WebEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) **does** have the `getLocation()` method... So get the engine from your `WebView` and you can get the URL.

Comment: the api doc is your friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add onto Zephyr's answer I would like to give you the code you need:

```html
browserName.getEngine().load("https://www." + urlFieldName.getText());
urlFieldName.setText(browserName.getEngine().getLocation());
```

Comment: Is it also possible to elaborate on what your code does to support the context?

Comment: It just adds the code that is needed to get the url.